# Passing data from UIViewController to UIView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a table in an UIViewController, I also have a sub view which is UIView.
I was trying to pass data from my UIViewController to the UIView:

MainViewController:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UAModalPanel *mainSubModalPanel = [[[MainSubView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:mainSubModalPanel];
    [mainSubModalPanel showFromPoint:CGPointMake(384.5, 512.5)];

}
```

MainSubView.h

```
@interface MainSubView : UAModalPanel
{
    NSString *dishName;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *dishName;
```

However I then have trouble in passing data from my table view to "dishName" in sub view and set the "mainTitle" = "dishName"
Anyone could help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you're storing your newly-allocated `MainSubView` in a `UAModalPanel` pointer although the properties you need to access are part of your `MainSubView` subclass.  Try changing the `MainSubView` initialization to:

```
    MainSubView *mainSubModalPanel = [[[MainSubView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds] autorelease];
```

Now you should be able to set `dishName` and `mainTitle`'s [`text`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/Reference/UILabel.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text):

```
    mainSubModalPanel.dishName = @"Pizza!";
    mainSubModalPanel.mainTitle.text = @"Moar Pizza!";
```

And then add it as a subview and whatever else as you have above *(I like to set up an object completely before passing ownership since it tends to lead to fewer glitches)*.

---

**Minor Notes:**

Your `NSString *dishName` property would probably be better to have the `copy` modifier rather than `retain`.  Foundation types that have mutable subtypes *(i.e. NSString has a NSMutableString subclass)* are subject to being passed a mutable subclass that can be changed from the outside.  Generally, this isn't what you want and leads to bugs *(unless of course you've asked for an NSMutableString explicitly)*, and using `copy` makes sure that whatever you're passed stays that way:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *dishName;
```

Also, if you're planning on having MainSubView's `mainTitle.text` match `dishName`, you may want to consider specifying a custom setter method for `dishName` that sets the `mainTitle.text` automatically like this:

```
- (void)setDishName:(NSString *)newDishName
{
    BOOL notTheSameStringInstance = (newDishName != dishName);
    BOOL notIdenticalStringContents = ![newDishName isEqualToString:dishName];
    if (notTheSameStringInstance && notIdenticalStringContents) {
        [dishName release];
        dishName = [newDishName copy];

        mainTitle.text = dishName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good.  Glad to have been able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust your init method to an init method where you pass data on.

```
MainSubView *mainSV = [[MainSubView alloc] initWithMyCustomData:(NSDictionary *)dictionaryObject andAnArray:(NSArray *)array andAString:(NSString *)string andANumber:(NSNumber *)aNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've subclassed UIView and called it MainSubView. Now, add some properties to your subclass and set them from the view controller.

Be sure to include the .h file for the custom UIView in the .h file of your UIViewController.

```
mainSubModalPanel.myProperty = myString;
```

Then, since you're creating the custom UIView in code, don't forget to add it as a subview of the UIViewController: